# Live animated Line or Area graph in a circula canvas viewport

Tags: javascript, graph, html5-canvas

I am fairly new to Javascript / HTML5 front end programming. I am wondering how to have a circular canvas view within which there is a live graph.

I have looked at D3.js and cubism for graphing and I have a brief understanding of using canvas for animation etc. Usually the graphs are displayed in a rectangular view, within which the graph is displayed.

Please see the image that I have attached. I have looked around and didn't find any libraries that would do it, so have decided to do it myself but need some points on how to go about it in an efficient manner.

So basically some form of masking as shown in the following image

[image]

resulting in the following type of graph

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtyCr.jpg]

Comment: you should definitely be able to do this with d3.  Do you want the circle on the graph to be tied to the movement of the mouse?

Comment: No. Circle on the graph is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the `context.clip` method to display your chart only within a circle:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var nextTime=0;
var delay=16*10;
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var radius=50;


var data=[];
for(var i=0;i<radius*2;i++){
  data.push(Math.random()*radius*2);
}

ctx.fillStyle='rgb(186,228,180)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.clip();

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if(time<nextTime){return;}

  nextTime+=delay;

  // new data point
  data.shift();
  data.push(Math.random()*radius*2);

  var x=cx-radius;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x,cy);
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    x+=5;
    ctx.lineTo(x,cy-radius+data[i]);
  }
  ctx.lineTo(cx+radius,cw);
  ctx.lineTo(cx-radius-1,cy+radius);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle='rgb(186,228,180)';
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @markE. This is awesome. I am going to try the clipping code with D3.js (which does the graphing) and get back here. And thanks for the edit.

Comment: Follow up question. D3 is SVG based. I would like to run at least 5-10 such graphs on a single page. Based on what I have read, canvas would be the best way to go forward. Am I right in my assumption? If yes, what would be a good library to use for charting with Angular which is Canvas based. I have looked around and there are tons of them. Being new, hard for me to evaluate.

Comment: Less than a dozen SVG elements will not cause performance problems--even on mobile. So, if you have more experience with D3 then you could certainly use D3--it's a great data visualization library (IMHO, the best!).  Similarly, if you just want to create some line charts, then you don't even need a charting library because canvas can easily do that. For example, just pull my answer apart and provide real data points rather than dummy data. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Had a question for you. I tried the code. I am seeing some unusual animation throttling. After the canvas is not in focus (because tab lost focus) and then the canvas received focus back again,the animation goes much faster, than the usual animation rate. Why is that? and what should I do for that to not happen?